# Error: Subprocess failed. Error: RPM failed: error: unpacking of archive failed on file /root/bin: cpio: chown

Tags: upgrade, filesystem

Error: Subprocess failed. Error: RPM failed: error: unpacking of archive failed on file /root/bin: cpio: chown        while running update filesystem not updating

Comment: Hello, can you please add more detail to your question for clarity?